# Speed up Postgresql Query and Function

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, performance

I have a tables that looks like this:

```
create_table "cboe_raws", force: :cascade do |t|
t.date "quote_date", null: false
t.string "underlying_symbol", null: false
t.string "security_type", null: false
t.string "option_symbol", null: false
t.date "expiration_date", null: false
t.float "strike_price", default: 0.0, null: false
t.string "call_put_flag", null: false
t.integer "days_to_expire", default: 0, null: false
t.string "series_type", null: false
t.float "first_trade_price", default: 0.0, null: false
t.float "high_trade_price", default: 0.0, null: false
t.float "low_trade_price", default: 0.0, null: false
t.float "last_trade_price", default: 0.0, null: false
t.integer "total_exchange_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "total_industry_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "open_interest", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "previous_open_interest", default: 0, null: false
t.float "previous_close", default: 0.0, null: false
t.integer "firm_open_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "firm_open_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "firm_close_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "firm_close_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "firm_open_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "firm_open_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "firm_close_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "firm_close_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "bd_open_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "bd_open_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "bd_close_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "bd_close_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "bd_open_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "bd_open_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "bd_close_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "bd_close_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "mm_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "mm_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "mm_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "mm_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_lt_100_open_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_lt_100_open_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_lt_100_close_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_lt_100_close_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_lt_100_open_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_lt_100_open_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_lt_100_close_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_lt_100_close_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_100_199_open_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_100_199_open_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_clsoe_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_100_199_close_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_100_199_open_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_100_199_open_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_100_199_close_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_100_199_close_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_open_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_open_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_close_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_close_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_open_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_open_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_close_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_close_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_lt_100_open_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_lt_100_open_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_lt_100_close_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_lt_100_close_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_lt_100_open_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_lt_100_open_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_lt_100_close_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_lt_100_close_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_100_199_open_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_100_199_open_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_100_199_close_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_100_199_close_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_100_199_open_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_100_199_open_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_100_199_close_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_100_199_close_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_gt_199_open_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_gt_199_open_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_gt_199_close_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_gt_199_open_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_gt_199_open_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_gt_199_close_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_gt_199_close_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.boolean "active", default: true, null: false
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer "cust_100_199_close_buy_qty"
t.integer "procust_gt_199_close_buy_qty"
t.index ["active"], name: "index_cboe_raws_on_active"
t.index ["call_put_flag"], name: "index_cboe_raws_on_call_put_flag"
t.index ["expiration_date"], name: "index_cboe_raws_on_expiration_date"
t.index ["option_symbol"], name: "index_cboe_raws_on_option_symbol"
t.index ["quote_date"], name: "index_cboe_raws_on_quote_date"
t.index ["strike_price"], name: "index_cboe_raws_on_strike_price"
```

I then ran a migration to add indexes:

```
  def change
    add_index :cboe_raws, :expiration_date
    add_index :cboe_raws, :call_put_flag
    add_index :cboe_raws, :quote_date
    add_index :cboe_raws, :active
    add_index :cboe_raws, :option_symbol
    add_index :cboe_raws, :strike_price
  end
end
```

I then created a DB function as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION market_maker_books (symbol VARCHAR)
    RETURNS TABLE (
        contract_underlying_symbol VARCHAR,
        contract_expiration_date DATE,
        contract_strike_price DOUBLE PRECISION,
        contract_call_put_flag VARCHAR,
        contract_mm_buy_vol_sum BIGINT,
        contract_mm_sell_vol_sum BIGINT,
        contract_buys_minus_sells BIGINT
    )
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT underlying_symbol,
        expiration_date,
        strike_price,
        call_put_flag,
        SUM(mm_buy_vol) AS mm_buy_vol_sum,
        SUM(mm_sell_vol) AS mm_sell_vol_sum,
        SUM(mm_buy_vol) - SUM(mm_sell_vol) AS buys_minus_sells
      FROM cboe_raws
      WHERE underlying_symbol = symbol AND expiration_date >= CURRENT_DATE
      GROUP BY underlying_symbol, expiration_date, strike_price, call_put_flag
      ORDER BY expiration_date, call_put_flag, strike_price;
    END; $$

    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Calling the function above takes about 18-19 seconds on a databse with 8.6 million rows.
I need that to be much much faster, because this database is only going to grow.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I can speed this up?

Thanks

Comment: How often does this data change (e.g. does this need to be live and dynamic)? Your best bet from a performance standpoint is likely to create a new table to store the rolled up data and query that. You could create a job (overnight?) that updates/repopulates this table. As an aside, because this query works as is this question is probably better suited for [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I do not see an index on `underlying_symbol`.  Did I miss it?

Comment: You might want to start by looking at what EXPLAIN says about your query.

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes it needs to be dynamic because data every day is falling off as expired. It does run in an overnight job.

Comment: @MikeOrganek good catch!